# Recourse for CAN-SPAM violation (impossible to unsubscribe)

Tags: united-states, texas, can-spam-act-of-2003

According to CAN-SPAM, it should be possible to unsubscribe from a given vendor without much issue or fuss (emphasis added for the relevant part):

https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

> You can’t charge a fee, require the recipient to give you any personally identifying information beyond an email address, or make the recipient take any step other than sending a reply email or *visiting a single page on an Internet website as a condition for honoring an opt-out request*.

I'm in Texas, I've tried unsubscribing from some list via their webpage, but it seems like the vendor's system isn't working properly, and I still continue receiving the emails past the 10 days.

Moreover, these emails come with *misleading and deceptive e-mail subject headers*, which I personally find disturbing and would classify as the real "fake news".

Do I have any recourse?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the email has the requisite properties (is commercial advertising or promotion – not transactional or relationship) and that you submitted the request with 30 days of receipt, you can complain to the FTC, [as described here](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0038-spam). The online complain interface is [here](https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/#&panel1-1). If you are an internet service provider and have been adversely affected then under [15 USC 7706(g)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/7706) you may sue the offender for damages.

Texas has an [analog of CAN-SPAM](http://law.justia.com/codes/texas/2005/bc/004.00.000046.00.html) (which, the Texas AG [points out](https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/cpd/spam-unsolicited-emails#laws), is superseded in some sections by federal law). There doesn't currently appear to be an active mechanism for complaining to the Texas AG, but maybe it just requires a phone call.

Comment: do you at all know if there's a state law that possibly pre-empts?